# CentOS Server network is accessible but terminal not responding

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, terminal, centos

I run a `CentOS7x86` Server.

The follow problem happens so frequently but I got no clue where to look at.

1. Run Server
2. Run some `docker` containers (`Jenkins`, `gitlab` ...)
3. It looks fine, but several days later, can not access with `ssh`
4. In the situation of `3`, `ping` to server looks fine but can not access with `ssh`
5. Also in the server device, at first terminal looks fine(waiting user inputs.) but as soon as whatever command I put it, hangs.(For Example, I was tried `firewall-cmd --list-port`)
6. When I use `top` before, it has enough memory

How can I fix this problem?

- May I assume it is only network problem, since I can access with `ping`?
- Is it possible only port `22` blocked?

I need any advice to how to get started with this kind of problem. Thanks.

================== EDIT ========================

`sar` command reports like follow

```
[ice@ice ~]$ sar
Linux 3.10.0-123.el7.x86_64 (DCSF-DEV08)    08/03/2017  _x86_64_    (24 CPU)

12:00:01 AM     CPU     %user     %nice   %system   %iowait    %steal     %idle
12:10:01 AM     all      2.74      0.00      1.62      0.02      0.00     95.62
12:20:01 AM     all      2.74      0.00      1.62      0.02      0.00     95.62
12:30:01 AM     all      2.74      0.00      1.61      0.02      0.00     95.62
12:40:01 AM     all      2.74      0.00      1.62      0.02      0.00     95.62
12:50:01 AM     all      2.75      0.00      1.62      0.02      0.00     95.62
01:00:01 AM     all      2.74      0.00      1.62      0.02      0.00     95.62
01:10:01 AM     all      2.74      0.00      1.62      0.02      0.00     95.62
01:20:01 AM     all      2.75      0.00      1.61      0.02      0.00     95.62
01:30:01 AM     all      2.74      0.00      1.62      0.02      0.00     95.62
01:40:01 AM     all      2.74      0.00      1.62      0.02      0.00     95.62
01:50:01 AM     all      2.74      0.00      1.62      0.02      0.00     95.62
02:00:02 AM     all      2.74      0.00      1.62      0.02      0.00     95.63
02:10:01 AM     all      2.74      0.00      1.62      0.02      0.00     95.63
02:20:01 AM     all      2.74      0.00      1.62      0.02      0.00     95.62
02:30:01 AM     all      2.74      0.00      1.62      0.02      0.00     95.62
02:40:01 AM     all      2.74      0.00      1.62      0.02      0.00     95.63
02:50:01 AM     all      2.74      0.00      1.62      0.02      0.00     95.62
03:00:01 AM     all      2.74      0.00      1.62      0.02      0.00     95.62
03:10:01 AM     all      2.75      0.00      1.61      0.02      0.00     95.62
03:20:01 AM     all      2.74      0.00      1.62      0.02      0.00     95.62
03:30:01 AM     all      2.74      0.00      1.62      0.02      0.00     95.62
03:40:01 AM     all      2.74      0.00      1.62      0.02      0.00     95.62
03:50:01 AM     all      2.74      0.00      1.62      0.02      0.00     95.62
04:00:01 AM     all      2.74      0.00      1.62      0.02      0.00     95.62
04:10:01 AM     all      2.74      0.00      1.63      0.02      0.00     95.62
04:20:01 AM     all      2.74      0.00      1.62      0.02      0.00     95.62
04:30:01 AM     all      2.74      0.00      1.62      0.02      0.00     95.62
04:40:01 AM     all      2.75      0.00      1.61      0.02      0.00     95.62
04:50:01 AM     all      2.74      0.00      1.62      0.02      0.00     95.62
05:00:02 AM     all      2.74      0.00      1.62      0.02      0.00     95.62
05:10:01 AM     all      2.75      0.00      1.62      0.02      0.00     95.62
05:20:01 AM     all      2.74      0.00      1.62      0.02      0.00     95.62
05:30:01 AM     all      2.75      0.00      1.61      0.02      0.00     95.62
05:40:01 AM     all      2.75      0.00      1.62      0.02      0.00     95.62
05:50:01 AM     all      2.74      0.00      1.62      0.02      0.00     95.62
06:00:01 AM     all      2.74      0.00      1.62      0.02      0.00     95.62
06:10:01 AM     all      2.75      0.00      1.61      0.02      0.00     95.62
06:20:01 AM     all      2.74      0.00      1.62      0.02      0.00     95.62
06:30:01 AM     all      2.75      0.00      1.62      0.02      0.00     95.62
06:40:01 AM     all      2.75      0.00      1.62      0.02      0.00     95.62
06:50:01 AM     all      2.75      0.00      1.61      0.02      0.00     95.62
07:00:01 AM     all      2.74      0.00      1.62      0.02      0.00     95.62
07:10:01 AM     all      2.75      0.00      1.62      0.02      0.00     95.62
07:20:01 AM     all      2.74      0.00      1.62      0.02      0.00     95.62
07:30:01 AM     all      2.74      0.00      1.62      0.02      0.00     95.62
07:40:01 AM     all      2.74      0.00      1.62      0.02      0.00     95.62
07:50:02 AM     all      2.74      0.00      1.62      0.02      0.00     95.63
08:00:01 AM     all      2.75      0.00      1.61      0.02      0.00     95.62

08:00:01 AM     CPU     %user     %nice   %system   %iowait    %steal     %idle
08:10:01 AM     all      2.74      0.00      1.62      0.02      0.00     95.62
08:20:01 AM     all      2.75      0.00      1.61      0.02      0.00     95.62
08:30:01 AM     all      2.74      0.00      1.62      0.02      0.00     95.62
08:40:01 AM     all      2.74      0.00      1.62      0.02      0.00     95.62
08:50:01 AM     all      2.74      0.00      1.61      0.02      0.00     95.63
09:00:01 AM     all      2.74      0.00      1.62      0.02      0.00     95.62
09:10:01 AM     all      2.74      0.00      1.61      0.02      0.00     95.63
09:20:01 AM     all      2.74      0.00      1.62      0.02      0.00     95.62
09:30:01 AM     all      2.75      0.00      1.61      0.02      0.00     95.63
09:40:01 AM     all      2.74      0.00      1.61      0.02      0.00     95.62
09:50:01 AM     all      2.74      0.00      1.62      0.02      0.00     95.62
10:00:01 AM     all      2.79      0.00      1.64      0.02      0.00     95.55
10:10:01 AM     all      2.75      0.00      1.62      0.02      0.00     95.62
Average:        all      2.74      0.00      1.62      0.02      0.00     95.62
```

To me, since `idle` is more than 90%, memory issue should not happened.

FYI, my swap setting is(`sysctl -a | grep swappiness`) :

```
vm.swappiness = 60
```

Comment: If it is hanging in the console, then the cpu is probably saturated - usually this would be because of i/o wait for memory if memory is full, and swapping is slowing things down dramatically.. If you leave `uptime` for ages, does it eventially come back?  That will tell you if it is cpu load.

Comment: Thanks @Paul yes. it looks like `virsh` image took too much memory. And unfortunately it did not come back to normal. So I have to reboot the device. However is there any system log which can tell why suddenly swap memory usage become so high? I got `systemstat`, but it does not tell specific reasons.

Comment: It is hard to work out what happened after the fact.  Presumably you have memory limits on the containers?

Comment: @Paul I got 4 docker containers running and 1 `qemu` VM. When it happens 4 docker service is still active but qemu service was down. So I just guess my qemu VM setting has some memory issue. It was very helpful  explanation for me(who just started with server device management). Thanks so much

Comment: @Paul If you do not mind, I would like to provide some more information. I add some extra infos to my original post. As far as I searched from internet, when user usage is over 60%, it will use swap. However since idle is more than 90%, swap should not be matters. Is there any suggestion to prevent such server problem?

Comment: It depends a bit on what you are up to.  If this is a production environment then you should ideally have external monitoring of the mem, cpu, hd usage so that you can be alerted when things are headed in the wrong direction so you can get on and troubleshoot before it falls to bits.